# Does the bandwidth of an NBFM modulation change depending with the modulation index?

Tags: rf, signal, communication, signal-processing, matlab

Hello electrical community ! I'm learning about FM Modulation ,especially with  narrow Band FM.And I was wondering if the index of modulation BETA affect the bandwidth of the modulated signal.
In fact , I tried simulation with MATLAB , but I didn't notice change in the bandwidth.
The formula I used is the Carson one:

$$B = 2(\beta +1)f_{m}$$

But I saw that in NBFM the bandwidth was defined like this :

$$B = 2f_{m}$$

Which one should I use ? by choosing the correct one , I think that I will be able to answer my problem which is : '''Does the bandwidth of an  NBFM modulation change depending with the modulation index?'''

Comment: Homework?  What is \$\beta\$ in the Carson formula?  Where does it come from?

Comment: The  $\beta$ in the Carson formula represents the modulation index . Its not a homework ,Just a curiosity , I wondered why when increasing the index modulation ,the number of spectral line didn't increase ,then this question came into my mind

Comment: Sorry for being coy -- it sounded a lot like homework.  Both the answers so far are good ones.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that your quantity beta is the maximum momentary frequency offset per the maximum baseband signal frequency fm. That beta is called "modulation index" and it exists in the approximated formula of the needed transmission bandwidth which is the uppermost of your bandwidth formula options.

In narrow band FM the modulation index is much smaller than 1. It makes the needed transmission bandwidth same as for AM and your both bandwidth formula options make quite the same result.

Use the 2nd option if the beta is say 0,1  or even less. But if you know the beta you can as well use the 1st option because it's valid for small and large beta.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ,now I better understand the concept

Answer (score 4):

First note that the Carlson formula is only an approximation. Second, narrowband FM is defined as FM modulation for which the modulation index is small compared to one. When this is the case, the Carlson formula reduces to the simpler formula and the spectrum of a narrowband FM signal is just the carrier and two sidebands spaced by the modulation frequency. This is actually very similar to AM except the phase of the sidebands differ. To answer your question, then, for narrowband FM the modulation index does not affect the bandwidth provided it is sufficiently small.